# Add a mouseover to make move my progress bar -JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is not working, i'm trying to make move the color inside my progress bar with a "mouseover" event but it's not working :

```
const myProgressAnim=document.getElementById('#Progress_Status');
myProgressAnim.addEventListener("mouseover",progressBar);

function progressBar(event){
  const myProgressElm=document.getElementById('#myprogressBar');
  document.myProgressElm.style.widht='100px';
  document.myProgressElm.style.backgroundColor="red";
  document.myProgressElm.style.color='black';
}
```

Comment: first of all, typo in `widht` maybe?

Comment: why prefixing document before myProgressElm, it should be only `myProgressElm`. (`myProgressElm.style.width='100px'` is enough)

Comment: you don't need to use '#' when using getElementByID method . unless you have set it like <div id='#Progress_status'>. please share your html code as well